# Windows 11 turns screen off instead of going into hibernate

Tags: windows, windows-11, hibernate

## Problem description

I've just freshly built a new PC and installed a fresh Windows 11.
However I've the problem that when I want it to go into hibernate, it instead keeps everything on (fans, pump, rgb on keyboard, speaker, mouse, mainboard), except for the screen, which will go into power saving mode.
When I move the mouse, or press a button on the keyboard, it will instantly greet me with the lock screen.

I tried everything I could come up with and find on the internet. However I'm unable to find the reason why it is not working.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

## What the reports show

This is from the **event log** from the Kernel-Power source:

- An attempt was made by a process in user mode to change the system state by calling the SetSuspendState or SetSystemPowerState API.
- The system session has changed from 0 to 1.
  Cause: ScreenOffGracePeriod
  BootId: 13
- The system session has changed from 1 to 2.
  Cause: SxTransition
  BootId: 13
- The system session has changed from 2 to 4.
  Cause: InputHid
  BootId: 13

This is from `powercfg /systempowerreport`
System Power State: Screen Off

| SESSION ID | START TIME | DURATION | STATE | ENTRY REASON | EXIT REASON | % CAPACITY REMAINING AT START |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 70 | 2024-03-18 20:33:54 | 0:00:01 | Screen Off | Hibernate, or Shutdown | Input Mouse | - |
| 71 | 2024-03-18 20:34:29 | 0:13:25 | Active | ---- | Unknown | - |
| 72 | 2024-03-18 20:47:55 | 0:00:00 | Report Generated | ---- | ---- | - |

`powercfg /requests` shows nothing in any category

## What I did so far:

**Hardware**

- Unplugged everything except for monitor and mouse/keyboard (tested both separately)

**UEFI**

- Disable WOL
- Disable Wake Timers
- Enabled ErP

**powercfg**

- `powercfg /h OFF` followed by `powercfg /h ON`
- `powercfg /h /type FULL`

**Device Manager**

- Went through all devices and disabled wake up events for every device that was capable

**Control Panel > Power options**

- Turn off monitor after: never
- Disabled wake timers
- Allow USB energy saving

**Windows features**

- Ensured that Hyper-V is *not* installed

Comment: Hibernate is often tricky to implement and needs the proper BIOS (UEFI) to work properly. That is the only other thing I can think of here.

Comment: Is UEFI fully updated? What is your motherboard? Tries: Run the Power Troubleshooter, disable Fast Startup

Comment: It is a GIGABYTE B650E AORUS Elite X AX ICE running the latest F3b Firmware. Fast Boot in UEFI is disabled and Fast Startup in Windows is disabled too, as it shows the same problem as hibernate (afaik it is essentially the same as hibernate, but it closes all apps before going into hibernation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest Windows Update seemed to fix the issue.
I'm now on 26085.1 ge_release.240315-1352 and the issue is just gone.